# Custom "Mat.at()"-like-function in OpenCV for better readability and still maintaining speed

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, mat

I've read that for Mat, pointer access (getting a pointer to the row, then accessing the column with []) is the fastest way of accessing it. I personally though really like the at()-function, since it's much easier to read and understand.
So I thought that one could just "wrap" the pointer access in a nicer function to maintain readability and fast access, for example something like:

```
uchar getMatValue(Mat &matrix, int row, int col)
{
    const uchar* Mi = matrix.ptr<uchar>(row);
    return Mi[col];
}
```

Would this access be actually fast at all? Or would the repeated access of the same row-pointer over and over be slower than just doing it 'the normal way'? Is there maybe a different (and better way) to do this?

I'm pretty new to OpenCV-Programming and c++, so I wonder if anyone has tried something similar like this for better readability.

Comment: not all Mat's are uchar (actually, most are not). just use Mat::at, until you learn, how to avoid per-pixel operations in favour of higher-level functions.

Comment: your code is a _bad_ implementation of the `at` function, so you better use `at`. To improve readability, you can use `Mat_<Tp>`, i.e. `Mat3b`, `Mat1f` etc... and access them using only the parentheses (without the _at<Tp>_).

Comment: Also, before doing any _optimization_, **first profile**!